# $[B/\mathfrak{P}^n:A/p]=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}[\mathfrak{P}^k/\mathfrak{P}^{k+1}:A/p]=n[B/\mathfrak{P}:A/p]$

Tags: extension-field, dedekind-domain

If $A$ is a Dedekind domain with field of quotients $K$, $L$ is a finite separable extension of $K$ and $B$ is the integral closure of $A$ in $L$ then it is known that $B$ is also a Dedekind domain.
Now if $p$ is a maximal ideal of $A$ and $\mathfrak{P}$ is a maximal ideal of $B$ such that $\mathfrak{P}\cap A=p$ then how exactly do we prove the following relation :
$[B/\mathfrak{P}^n:A/p]=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}[\mathfrak{P}^k/\mathfrak{P}^{k+1}:A/p]=n[B/\mathfrak{P}:A/p]$ where $n=e_{\mathfrak{P}}$.
I think that I managed to prove the first equality :
$[\mathfrak{P}^k/\mathfrak{P}^{k+1}:A/p]=[(\mathfrak{P}^k/\mathfrak{P}^n)/(\mathfrak{P}^{k+1}/\mathfrak{P}^n):A/p]=[\mathfrak{P}^k/\mathfrak{P}^{n}:A/p]-[\mathfrak{P}^{k+1}/\mathfrak{P}^{n}:A/p]$
So $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}[\mathfrak{P}^k/\mathfrak{P}^{k+1}:A/p]=[B/\mathfrak{P}^n:A/p]$.
Is this correct ?
As for the second equality, it seems that I have to prove that $[\mathfrak{P}^k/\mathfrak{P}^{k+1}:A/p]=[B/\mathfrak{P}:A/p]\ \forall 0\le k<n$. I don't know how to prove it though.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the meaning of $[B/\mathfrak{P}^n:A/p]$ ? Maybe you meant $n\le e(\mathfrak{P}|p)$, ie. $p\subset \mathfrak{P}^n$ in which case $B/\mathfrak{P}^n$ is a $A/p$ vector space.

Comment: In that case use the main property of Dedekind domains: that $\mathfrak{P}$ becomes principal $=(\pi)$ in $B/\mathfrak{P}^n$, then it is easy to show that $(\pi)^k/(\pi)^{k+1}\cong B/(\pi)$ as $B/(\pi)$ and $A/p$ vector spaces.

Comment: @reuns : actually $n=[L:K]$ and $[B/\mathfrak{P}^n:A/p]$ is the dimension of $B/\mathfrak{P}^n$ as an $A/p-$vector space. I forgot to mention that in my post, I'll edit it rightaway.

Comment: No, you need $n\le e$ for it to be a $A/p$ vector space. Otherwise it is only a $A/p^{\lceil n/e\rceil}$ module. For example $\Bbb{Z}[i]/(3)^2$ has characteristic $9$ it is not a $\Bbb{Z}/(3)$ vector space.

Comment: @reuns : You're right, I see. Just one more question please : does $\mathfrak{P}$ become principal in $B/\mathfrak{P}^n$ because this ring is isomorphic to $B_\mathfrak{P}/(\mathfrak{P}^nB_{\mathfrak{P}})$ and $B_{\mathfrak{P}}$ is a principal domain (since it's a DVR) ? Sorry but I'm new to Dedekind domains and I'm not quite comfortable with them yet.

Comment: Yes, for a maximal ideal $m$ then $m$ is the only maximal ideal containing $\{ r^n,r\in m\}\subset m^n$ thus for $a\not \in m$ then $(a,m^n)$ is contained in no maximal ideal ie. $a\in (R/m^n)^\times$ and hence $R/m^n=R_m/m^n$.